# I want to check the occurrence of a particular item in all other items (even be it a sub string)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to check the occurrence of a particular item in all other items (even be it a sub string) .

```
n_a = ['28', '4663', '66', '66']
occ_arr = [[0,0]]*len(n_a)
for i in range(len(n_a)):
    count=0
    for j in range(len(n_a)):
        if n_a[i] in n_a[j]:
            count+=1
    occ_arr[i][0] = n_a[i]
    occ_arr[i][1] = count
print(occ_arr)
```

This is my piece of code.

The result is
 `[['66', 3], ['66', 3], ['66', 3], ['66', 3]]`

but the desired output is 
`[['28', 1], ['4663', 1], ['66', 3], ['66',3]]`.

Please help  me to figure out what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

```
occ_arr = [[0,0]]*len(n_a)
```

To:

```
occ_arr = []
for i in range(len(n_a)):
    occ_arr.append([0,0])
```

Will fix the bug occuring with the program. If you want to make this a one line statement, use the following list comprehension:

```
occ_arr = [[0,0] for _ in n_a]
           #Add the list [0,0] for each item in the list n_a
```

All together, the program turns into (using the one line solution):

```
n_a = ['28', '4663', '66', '66']


occ_arr = [[0,0] for _ in n_a]

for i in range(len(n_a)):
    count=0
    for j in range(len(n_a)):
        if n_a[i] in n_a[j]:
            count+=1
    occ_arr[i][0] = n_a[i]
    occ_arr[i][1] = count
    print(occ_arr)
print(occ_arr)
```

---

*Explanation of bug*

The reason why the bug occurs is because of the way lists are stored. Rather than being stored as literal data (like `int`s, `float`s, etc...), they are stored as objects, with memory addresses and ids. The line:

```
cc_arr = [[0,0]]*len(n_a)
```

Creates a list with it's own unique id and then copies it (shallowly [copying just the memory address, rather than the data]) four times. This can be shown through the following example:

```
>>> x = [[0,0]] * 4
>>> for item in x:
...     print(id(x))
4500701640
4500701640
4500701640
4500701640
```

*Note that the output will be different for you.*

Hence, when you change one list, you change the underlying representation of the object, which changes the other shallow copies, which is why your program was outputting `[['66', 3], ['66', 3], ['66', 3], ['66', 3]]` rather than `[['28', 1], ['4663', 1], ['66', 3], ['66',3]]`

Answer (score 2):

All your sub-lists in the `occ_arr` list are referencing the same list because you're using the `*` operator to copy the reference of the same list, so any change in one sub-list is reflected on all the other sub-lists. You should instead use list comprehension to create a distinct sub-lists.

Change:

```
occ_arr = [[0,0]]*len(n_a)
```

to:

```
occ_arr = [[0,0] for _ in range(len(n_a))]
```